# How to detect has user installed an app by mobile website

Tags: mobile

Some mobile website will recommend you install some app, I think it's just bring out the app information if detected you are using mobile device, but some website will note bring out the information if you already installed the app, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can store information in a database, a cookie, the localStorage or a native app. Let's suppose that you have a FooInstalled which might be null or true. You prompt your user to install foo and when you see it was installed, you set FooInstalled to true. Later, when he visits your site, you read FooInstalled from your database/cookie/localStorage/native app storage and see that it is true. So you don't ask your user to install foo.